# Drupal - Tinynav js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

When my website passes through the defined pixel threshold as stated in Tinynav.js module all the menu items appear as they should minus the parent menu items. I have defined the parent items through Special Menu Items module as no link, meaning the parent div is simply a placeholder for the child menu items and doesn't link to any content. The issue is when the website passes into the threshold and the dropdown scrollable menu appears in place of the navigational menu it doesn't show the parent items only the child items linked to the parent.

It seems because the parent item has been defined as a no link the Tiny.js module skips it and simply displays the child menu. I have tried multiple things and none have worked, I have uploaded the js associated with Tinynav.js and html so it can be edited.

It could be the editing of this file or something else.

Thanks for helping out

html

```
<div id="nav"><!--nav-->
<ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li class="leaf"><a href="/node" title="" class="active">Public Courses</a></li>
    <li class="expanded"><span title="" class="nolink">Tradition </span><ul class="menu">          <li class="first leaf"><a href="/Egypt">Egypt</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/node/8">Tibet</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="expanded"><a href="/node" title="" class="active">For Reflection</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/current-reflections">Current Reflections</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/past-reflections">Past Reflections</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="last leaf active-trail"><a href="/node" title="" class="active-trail active">About Us</a></li>
</ul>           
        </div><!--/nav-->
```

tinynav-fork.js

```
/*! Originally based on the tinynav.js library found at http://tinynav.viljamis.com by @viljamis */
(function ($, window, i) {
  $.fn.tinyNav = function (options) {
    // Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      'active' : 'selected', // String: Set the "active" class
      'header' : false, // Boolean: Show header instead of the active item
      'indent' : '--', // String: Set this to empty to disable identing
      'depth_count' : 2 // Integer: depth to stop counting
    }, options);
    return this.each(function () {
      // Used for namespacing
      i++;
      var $nav = $(this),
        // Namespacing
        namespace = 'tinynav',
        namespace_i = namespace + i,
        l_namespace_i = '.l_' + namespace_i,
        $select = $('<select/>').addClass(namespace + ' ' + namespace_i);
      if ($nav.is('ul,ol')) {
        if (settings.header) {
          $select.append(
            $('<option value="-null-"/>').text(Drupal.t('Navigation'))
          );
        }
        // Build options
        var options = '';
        $nav
          .addClass('l_' + namespace_i)
          .find('a')
          .each(function () {
            var indent = '';
            // indent once for each parent this has
            var parent_count = $(this).parents("ul,ol").length;
            // apply indenting if found
            for (var i=1; i<parent_count; i++) {
              indent += settings.indent;
            }
            // add spacing to end if we indent at all
            if (indent != '') {
              indent += ' ';
            }
            if (parent_count < settings.depth_count) {
              options +=
                '<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' +
                indent + $(this).text() +
                '</option>';
            }
          });
        // Append options into a select
        $select.append(options);
        // Select the active item
          $select
            .find(':eq(' + (settings.header + $(l_namespace_i + ' li')
            .index($(l_namespace_i + ' .' + settings.active)) + ')'))
            .attr('selected', true);

        // Change window location
        $select.change(function () {
          if ($(this).val() != '-null-') {
            window.location.href = $(this).val();
          }
        });
        // Inject select
        $(l_namespace_i).after($select);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery, this, 0);
```

tinynav-drupal.js

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.tinynav = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // make sure we don't try to access an undefined array
      settings.tinynav = settings.tinynav || {
        selector: '#nav ul',
        media_query: 'all and (max-width:795px)',
        header: false,
        active: 'active-trail'

      }
      // Add the class to the selectors so we can access it later
      $(settings.tinynav.selector).addClass('tinyjs');

      // Build the Settings array
      var tinyNavSettings = {
        header: settings.tinynav.header
      };
      if (settings.tinynav.active) {
        tinyNavSettings.active = settings.tinynav.active;
      }

      // Tinynav (<-- new verb) them all
      $('.tinyjs').tinyNav(tinyNavSettings);
      // Add a wrapper to the select element
      $('select.tinynav').wrap('<div class="tinynav-wrapper"/>');
    },
    weight: 99
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Tinynav.js module because it's looking for an

```
<a>
```

but Special Menu Items module create a

```
<span>
```

this is a working code:

```
/*! http://tinynav.viljamis.com v1.03 by @viljamis 
modified by l.tagliamonte to fix Special Menu Items module menu links*/
(function ($, window, i) {
$.fn.tinyNav = function (options) {

// Default settings
var settings = $.extend({
  'active' : 'selected', // String: Set the "active" class
  'header' : false // Boolean: Show header instead of the active item
}, options);

return this.each(function () {

  // Used for namespacing
  i++;

  var $nav = $(this),
    // Namespacing
    namespace = 'tinynav',
    namespace_i = namespace + i,
    l_namespace_i = '.l_' + namespace_i,
    $select = $('<select/>').addClass(namespace + ' ' + namespace_i);

  if ($nav.is('ul,ol')) {

    if (settings.header) {
      $select.append(
        $('<option/>').text('Navigation')
      );
    }

    // Build options
    var options = '';
    var indent = 0;
    var indented = ["&nbsp;"];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      indented.push(indented[indented.length-1]+indented[indented.length-1]);
    }
    indented[0] = "";
    $nav
      .addClass('l_' + namespace_i)
      .children('li')
      .each(buildNavTree=function () {
        var a = $(this).children('a').first();
        var nolink = $(this).children('span.nolink').first();

        if (nolink.html() != null){
            options +=
          '<option value="' + nolink.html() + '" disabled>' +
          indented[indent] + nolink.html() +
          '</option>';
        }else{
        options +=
          '<option value="' + a.attr('href') + '">' +
          indented[indent] + a.text() +
          '</option>';
          }
          indent++;
          $(this).children('ul,ol').children('li').each(buildNavTree);
          indent--;
      });

    // Append options into a select
    $select.append(options);

    // Select the active item
    if (!settings.header) {
      $select
        .find(':eq(' + $(l_namespace_i + ' li')
        .index($(l_namespace_i + ' li.' + settings.active)) + ')')
        .attr('selected', true);
    }

    // Change window location
    $select.change(function () {
      window.location.href = $(this).val();
    });

    // Inject select
    $(l_namespace_i).after($select);

  }

$('option[value="'+document.location+'"]').attr("selected","selected");

});

};
})(jQuery, this, 0);

// Tinynav
jQuery(function(){
// Main Menu
jQuery('#main-menu > ul.menu').tinyNav({
    active: 'selected', // Set the "active" class
});
});
```